# Is Muhammad's tribe eminent?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, prophet-muhammad, sunnah, contradiction

> "Wathila b. al-Asqa’ reported: I heard Allah’s Messenger (may peace be
> upon him) as saying: Verily Allah granted eminence to Kinana from
> amongst the descendants of Isma’il and he granted eminence to the
> Quraish amongst Kinana and he granted eminence to the Quraish amongst
> Banu Hashim and he granted me eminences from the tribe of Banu
> Hashim." (Sahih Muslim 30:5653)

This hadith to me, seems to contradict with

> "Abu Malik al-Ash’ari reported Allah’s Messenger (may peace be upon
> him) as saying: Among my people there are four characteristics
> belonging to pre-Islamic period which they do not abandon: boasting of
> high rank, reviling other peoples’ genealogies, seeking rain by stars,
> and walling. And he (further) said: If the wailing woman does not
> repent before she dies, she will be made to stand on the Day of
> Resurrection wearing a garment of pitch and a chemise of mange."
> (Sahih Muslim 4:2033)

In the first hadith, he seems to be saying that the Quraish are of a higher rank than other tribes, but in the second hadith, he warns against boasting of high rank. Can anybody resolve the apparent contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being eminent is not the same thing as boasting about being eminent.

Boasting involves arrogance, the implication being that having more of something makes one *better* than those with less. But humility recognizes that whatever advantages, whatever privileges, whatever wealth, whatever strength, whatever *whatever* one has more than others comes from Allah — He gives and withholds His gifts as He wills — and in no way determines whether someone is better or worse in His eyes.

Simply acknowledging that one has gifts that another does not is not boasting.